# Getting ProtocolError "Must not send frame with WARNING flag for native protocol version < 4" with Java driver 3.11 on Cassandra 4.0

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

We are getting below error in driver & DB logs after upgrading to 4.0.Application team is currently using datastax java driver 3.11.0.

! com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ProtocolError: An unexpected protocol error occurred on host 101-142-43-18-ec2.internal/101.142.43.18:9042. This is a bug in this library, please report: Must not send frame with WARNING flag for native protocol version < 4

Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: A friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard back from you so I'm going to assume that you have hard-coded an older protocol version in your application, for example:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    ...
    .withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V3)
    .build();
```

The native protocol defines the format of the CQL binary messages between clients and the Cassandra cluster over TCP. Cassandra 2.1 introduced native protocol v3 ([CASSANDRA-6855](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6855)). C* 2.2 later added support for native protocol v4 ([CASSANDRA-8043](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8043)) which continued with Cassandra 3.0 and 3.11.

Cassandra 4.x also supports v4 but also added native protocol v5 ([CASSANDRA-14973](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14973)). Protocol v4 added the ability to send notification to clients if a query generates a warning ([CASSANDRA-8930](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8930)). Older protocols do not have the ability to send query warnings to clients so Cassandra understandably generates this error message:

```
    Must not send frame with WARNING flag for native protocol version < 4
```

In your app, you need to configure the driver to use a newer protocol version. Better still, Java driver 3.11 will automatically negotiate to using native protocol v5 when connecting to Cassandra 4.x unless you force the driver to use an older protocol version.

For details, see [Native protocol in Java driver 3.11](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/native_protocol/). Cheers!

Comment: Be careful with removing the app coding of the Protocol version.The reason this is typically done is to allow for rolling upgrades without breaking the applications using Cassandra. If the driver chooses the protocol version based on it initial connection to an upgraded version that supports a later protocol version, it will use that protocol version to connect to the non-upgraded nodes that may not support the protocol version the driver has already chosesn